# Missing github maven plugin artifact

Tags: maven, github, maven-3, maven-plugin

Tools:

> Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 12:31:09-0500) Maven home:
>   /usr/share/maven Java version: 1.6.0_43, vendor: Apple Inc. Java home:
>   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman OS name: "mac os
>   x", version: "10.8.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

I set the settings.xml and pom.xml as specified in the [documentation](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins) and after that ran the command:

> mvn clean install ghDownloads:upload

but the following error was thrown:

> No plugin found for prefix 'ghDownloads' in the current project and in
>   the plugin groups...

After that I was looking in corporate's Nexus repository but I cannot find that artifact.  Where ghDownloads resides?

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to put the following in the pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
            <artifactId>downloads-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <description>${project.version} release of ${project.name}</description>
                <override>true</override>
                <includeAttached>true</includeAttached>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```